# Android launching the same activity in different projects with a big difference in time consumption

Tags: android

Android the same Activity running in two projects on two projects to start the activity time consuming gap is very big one project is using gradle8.5,jdk17 another is gradle5.6.4,jdk11

Two projects rely on the same version of the library and did not do in the background time-consuming operation is simply by the. The two projects have the same version of dependencies and do not do any time-consuming operations in the background, but simply start the same Activity through startActivity (the code is the same, the layout xml is the same), and they are both running on the same phone.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't post logcat output as screenshot. Logcat output( you can use `adb logcat`) is text so just copy it and paste it into your question.